# Regular Expression for Simple Language

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm having trouble writing a regular expression given the following $\{a, b, c\}$ which produces the set of strings of length 3. I don't really understand how to restrict the length of the string. Obviously you could have 3 $a$'s, or 3 $b$'s or 3 $c$'s, but you could have $aab, aac, aba, \dots $

Is it something like $a^* \cup b^* \cup c^*$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular expression you have given gives the language
$$\{\varepsilon, a, aa, aaa, \dots\} \cup \{\varepsilon, b, bb, bbb, \dots\} \cup \{\varepsilon, c, cc, ccc, \dots\}$$
$$= \{\varepsilon, a, aa, aaa, \dots, b, bb, bbb, \dots, c, cc, ccc, \dots\},$$
which is clearly not what you are after.

Using only union ($\cup$), concatenation ($\circ$), and the Kleene star ($^*$), you could do something like
$$(a \cup b \cup c) \circ (a \cup b \cup c) \circ (a \cup b \cup c).$$

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, I will mention:

$$
\mathbf{aaa}\cup
\mathbf{aab}\cup
\mathbf{aac}\cup
\mathbf{aba}\cup
\mathbf{abb}\cup
\mathbf{abc}\cup
\mathbf{aca}\cup
\mathbf{acb}\cup
\mathbf{acc}\cup\\
\mathbf{baa}\cup
\mathbf{bab}\cup
\mathbf{bac}\cup
\mathbf{bba}\cup
\mathbf{bbb}\cup
\mathbf{bbc}\cup
\mathbf{bca}\cup
\mathbf{bcb}\cup
\mathbf{bcc}\cup\\
\mathbf{caa}\cup
\mathbf{cab}\cup
\mathbf{cac}\cup
\mathbf{cba}\cup
\mathbf{cbb}\cup
\mathbf{cbc}\cup
\mathbf{cca}\cup
\mathbf{ccb}\cup
\mathbf{ccc}
$$

It's useful to remember that finite languages are trivially regular.

Also, regular expressions do not have to be clever.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a purely algebraic answer, you could do this:

```
(a|b|c)(a|b|c)(a|b|c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
/[abc]{3}/g
```

Comment: This is great, but I'm looking for a more mathematical answer as opposed to a programming regular expression.

Comment: @user3270760 Programming language notation for regular expressions can almost always be easily converted to the notation used in CS textbooks.  For example, the `[abc]` notation is nothing but a shorthand for $(\mathbf a\cup\mathbf b\cup \mathbf c)$.

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be simply written as $((a+b+c)^3)^*$ since $(a+b+c)^3$ will produce all strings of length $3$.